# How to convert JS error positions to TypeScript error positions?

Tags: typescript

In a project of mine I allow users to enter TypeScript code which I then transpile and execute in a webworker via `eval`. This works fine and now I want to print messages originating from errors in the code. I can get the original JS code error position, which however does not correspond to the TS error position.

How can I convert the reported position?

```js
import ts, { ScriptTarget } from "typescript";

const jsCode = ts.transpile(tsCode, { alwaysStrict: true, target: ScriptTarget.ES2020 }),
worker.sendMessage({ task: "execute", code: jsCode });
```

In the worker I listen to error events and send back the error information to the application:

```js
worker.addEventListener("error", (event: ErrorEvent) => {
    worker.postContextMessage(worker.currentTaskId!, {
        api: ScriptingApi.Result,
        contextId: worker.currentContext!,
        result: `${event.message} (${event.colno}:${event.lineno})`,
        isError: true,
        final: true,
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I can enable creating inline source maps during transpilation, but that doesn't help here.